# C# Combination of DataTables for Calculations from SQL

Tags: c#, merge, ado.net

I've been looking over internet for a method of combining 2 datatables with exactly the same cells with numbers to add them together, Merge method never help because it just appended the second table. The task was later accomplished by my hand-written method:

```
static DataTable CombineDT34(DataTable dt3, DataTable dt4) {
            var combinedDT34 = dt3;
            for (var r3 = 0; r3 < dt3.Rows.Count; r3++) {

                for(var c3 = 1; c3 < dt3.Columns.Count; c3++) {

                    dt3.Rows[r3][c3] = 
                        (Convert.ToInt32(dt3.Rows[r3][c3]) +
                        Convert.ToInt32(dt4.Rows[r3][c3]));
                }
            }

            return dt3;
        }
```

Is there are a way to do this better? Thank you in advance

Comment: sql is not an appropriate tag for this question, so I removed it.

Comment: You could use more meaningful names, apart from that it's not clear what you want to improve. Improving working code is off-topic on SO anyway.

Comment: You should ask this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/